Is nonnegative $C_c^\infty$ dense in nonnegative $H_0^1$?
I have encountered the same problem as Replacing $C_c^\infty$ by $H_0^1$ in the definition of weak subsolution.
I wonder how to prove this statement there.

If $\phi\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ and $\phi \geq 0$, then there is a sequence $(\phi^n)$ in $C_0^\infty$ such that $\phi^n\geq 0$ and $\phi^n\to \phi$ in $H^1(\Omega)$.

Since from the definition of $H_0^1(\Omega)$, we only know that there exists $(\phi^n)$ in $C_0^\infty$ and $\phi^n\to \phi$ in $H^1(\Omega)$. What about the nonnegativity of $\phi^n$?

Every textbook I've ever seen that proves $C^\infty_c$ is dense in $H^1_0$ uses a mollification argument. Since the mollification of a non-negative function is non-negative, the proof of your statement will be exactly the same as the one in the textbooks

@JackT It is true that Evans (in Section 5.3) uses mollification argument and partition of unity to prove, for example, $C^\infty(\overline B_1)$ is dense in $H^1(B_1)$. But on the other hand, I think $W_0^{k,p}$ is by definition (not by construction) the closure of $C_c^\infty$ in $W^{k,p}$ (cf. Section 5.2.2). Maybe other books use different definitions?

Let $\phi_n\to \phi$, then also $\max(0,\phi_n) \to \phi$. Now mollify $\max(0,\phi_n) \approx \psi_n$. Then $\psi_n \ge0$, $\psi_n \in C_c^\infty$, $\psi_n \to \phi$ in $H^1$.

@daw I see $|\phi - \phi_n^+|{L^2} \leq |\phi - \phi_n|{L^2} \to 0$. But how to show $|\partial_i \phi_n - \partial_i \phi_n^+|{L^2}^2 = \int{{\phi_n \le 0}} |\partial_i \phi_n|^2 \to 0$ or $\int_{{\phi_n \le 0}} |\partial_i \phi|^2 \to 0$?

Let $\phi_n \to \phi$ in $H^1$ with $\phi \ge 0$. Then also $\phi_n^+ \to \phi$ in $H^1$:
Suppose that $\phi_n$ and $\nabla \phi_n$ converge pointwise a.e. to $\phi$ and $\nabla \phi$. (plus there exists an square integrable common upper bound of all these sequences)
We know that
$$
\nabla\phi_n^+(x) = \begin{cases} \nabla \phi_n(x) & \text{ if } \phi_n \ge0,\\
0 & \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}
$$
is true for almost all $x$.
Fix $x$ such that $\phi(x) >0$. Then $\phi_n(x) >0$ for $n$ large enough, and hence $\nabla\phi_n^+(x) = \nabla \phi_n(x) \to \nabla \phi(x)$.
In addition, $\nabla \phi=0$ a.e. on $\{x: \ \phi(x)=0\}$, which follows from the represenation of derivative of positive part.
So if $\phi(x) = 0$ then (for almost all such $x$) we have $\nabla \phi(x)=0$ and $\nabla\phi_n(x) \to0$, which implies $\nabla\phi_n^+(x) \to0$.
Now dominated convergence implies the claim.

Now $\phi_n^+$ are non-negative and continuous functions with compact support in $\Omega$. Mollification of $\phi_n^+$ results in a non-negative function $\psi_n \in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ close to $\phi_n^+$ in the $H^1$-norm.
